# Ayuda JSON encode PHP

Tags: php, json

Hola Tengo algo como esto desde un json_encode() en PHP

```
  ["texto1.","texto2","texto3"]
```

y quiero conseguir algo como esto

```
  "cast": [
    {
      "name": "texto1"
    },
    {
      "name": "texto2"
    },
    {
      "name": "texto3"
    }
  ]
```

Este es el código PHP que tengo:

```
<?php
    $json2 = file_get_contents('http://pastebin.com/raw/au4ds3bQ');
    $get2 = json_decode($json2);
    $a = "1";
    $a2 = $get2->data->$a->cast;
    echo json_encode($a2);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

podrias hacer algo como esto

```
<?php
    $json2 = file_get_contents('http://pastebin.com/raw/au4ds3bQ');
    $get2 = json_decode($json2);
    $a = "1";
    $a2 = $get2->data->$a->cast;
    $items = array();
    foreach ($a2 as $key => $value) {
        $items["cast"][] = array("name" => $value);
    }    
    echo json_encode($items);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

En este ejemplo [te dejé una muestra de cómo se podría hacer](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/717a7ef8f964a1b02745958f5400dff57ea5a40b), claro que reemplazé lo que obtienes de pastebin por un texto json_encoded.

Básicamente, `$get2` es un array no asociativo.

Declaro `$cast` como un array vacío

Por cada uno de los elementos de `$get2`, le añado un array asociativo `['name'=>$elemento]` a `$cast`.

El resultado final es un array asociativo `['cast'=>$cast];`

```
<?php

$json2= '["texto1.","texto2","texto3"]';

$get2=json_decode($json2);

$cast = [];

foreach($get2 as $elemento) {
    $cast[]=['name'=>$elemento];
}

$arrayfinal= ['cast'=>$cast];

print_r($arrayfinal);
```